# Send images which are not publicly accessible on the internet for Azure Face API Training

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I am using [Azure Face API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/apireference) for a face recognition project. I can only send images using URL. But since images are stored on our on-premise servers, authorisation is required to access those images using the URL. How can I pass images using the [REST API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f3039523b)

Comment: You can upload  an image in base 64 format, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/face/face/detectwithstream)

Comment: FYI *not* base64-encoded.  The HTTP body needs to contain the raw image bytes.